# $f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} x + xe^{\frac{1}{x}} & x < 0\\ 0 & x = 0\\ \frac{2-2\cos x}{\sin x} & 0 < x \end{matrix}\right.$ differentiate point

Tags: real-analysis

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
x + xe^{\frac{1}{x}} & x < 0\\ 
0 & x = 0\\ 
\frac{a-2\cos x}{\sin x} & 0 < x
\end{matrix}\right.$$

For $f(x)$ find the values of $a \in R$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

---

I want to find $a \in R$ such that $f'_{-}(0) = f'_+(0)$

Calculating $f_-(0)$ i get:

$$f'_-(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} 1 + e^{\frac{1}{x}} + x*-\frac{1}{x^2} 
e^{\frac{1}{x}} =  1 + 0 + \lim_{x \to 0^-} -\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$$

For $f_+(0)$:

$f'_+(x) = \displaystyle \frac{2-a\cos x}{\sin^2x}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{2-a\cos x}{\sin^2x} = \frac{2-a}{0 }$

I can't come up with any $a \in R$ that will give $f'_+(0) = 1$

Do you find any?

Comment: You even have the solution in the title!

Comment: At one point you suggest you are working with $\frac {2-2\cos x}{\sin x}$ at another it is $\frac {a-2\cos x}{\sin x}$ and at a third $\frac {2-a\cos x}{\sin x}$  Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=2$. Then,

$$f_+'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2\sin^2 x-(2-2\cos x)\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2(1-\cos x)}{\sin^2 x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{4\sin^2 (x/2)}{4\sin^2 (x/2) \cos^2 (x/2)}=1$$

where I used
\begin{equation*}
1-\cos (x)=2\sin^2 (x/2)
\end{equation*}
in the numerator and
$$\sin x=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$$
in the denominator.

Comment: I dont understand what you did in this stage: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2(1-\cos x)}{\sin^2 x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2\sin x}{2\sin x \cos x}=1$ its like you replace $(1-cosx)$ by $sinx$ and $sin^2x$ by $2sinxcosx$ and thats not true as far as i understand, so did you do something else?

Comment: Oh you used LHopital, i cant use it but it gives the asnwer, thanks

Comment: @Alon see my updated answer, which does not use L'Hôpital.

Comment: How did you get to $\displaystyle 1-cos(x) = 2sin^2(x/2)$? i tried to use the identity for: $cosa-cosb, a = 0, b = x \Rightarrow cos0-cosx$ but it didnt work

Comment: Oh i understand, now we use the identity $\displaystyle sin(-x) = -sin(x)$

Comment: Great, the $sin^2x = 4sin(x/2)cos(x/2)$ and we get $\frac{1}{cos^2x}$ and when $x \to 0+$ we get $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to calculate $f_+'(x)$ and I got $f_+'(x)=\frac{2-a\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$.

Then evaluate the limit approaching zero.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f_+'(x)=\frac{2-a}{0}$

In order that we have the limit to be a real value, we need the value to be $\frac00$. Thus we get $a=2$.

Check whether $a=2$ satisfies the original condition or not using the L'Hopital's rule and got the following,

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{2-2\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{2\sin(x)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{2}{2\cos(x)}=1$

In conclusion, the value for $a$ is $a=2$.

Comment: But you did use LHopital

Comment: Yes I use LHopital to check whether a=2 is a correct solution or not.